Excel macro to color a cell by validating or comparing cell values in different sheets
THIS DATA IS BASICALLY IDENTIFYING CORRECT CHOICES (A, B, C D)
I have a data as below in two sheets (Sheet1 & Sheet2). I need to compare or validate the cell value in both sheets and if the values are same based on the condition, then color the cell in Sheet1. The condition is, in Sheet2, get the cell value of A1 (ie.1) and then get the adjacent cell value next to cell A1, B1 (ie.A). Now if 1=A, then in Sheet1, look for 1 and A in colA and then color the cell which has value A. Simliarly repeat for all cell values in sheet2.
As per data shown below, based on Sheet2, 1=B, 2=D, 3=C. Then in Sheet1, in ColC, for 1, Cell value B must be colored in GREEN color, for 2, Cell value D must be colored in GREEN color, for 3, Cell value C must be colored in GREEN color,
Data as shown below:
Sheet1    Sheet2
ColC      ColA  ColB
1         1     B
A         2     D
B         3     C
C
D

2
A
B
C
D

3
A
B
C
D


Are the groups (1, 2, 3 etc.) separated by an empty row? Than, what does "ColC" mean? Should it mean Column C:C, or it's just a header In A:A?

Yes, there is an empty row to seperate each group. Column C:C.

Please, try the next VBA solution. It should be very fast using range Find and Match, then placing the cells to be colored in a Union range, to be colored at the end, at once:
Sub identifyChoices()
 Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, lastR1 As Long, lastR2 As Long, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
 Dim A As Range, rngA As Range, srcRng As Range, rngU As Range, mtch
 
 Set ws1 = Worksheets(1) 'use here the necessary sheet
 lastR1 = ws1.Range("C" & ws1.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row in C:C
 Set rng1 = ws1.Range("C2:C" & lastR1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) 'the range to be processed
 
 Set ws2 = Worksheets(2) 'use here the necessary sheet
 lastR2 = ws2.Range("A" & ws2.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 Set rng2 = ws2.Range("A2:A" & lastR2)
 
 rng1.Interior.Color = xlNone 'cleaer interior color of all the range
 For Each A In rng1.Areas     'iterate between the range areas (separated by empty cells):
    Set rngA = A.cells(1)     'first cell of the area is the search value
    Set srcRng = rng2.Find(rngA.value) 'find it in the next sheet, first column
    If Not srcRng Is Nothing Then      'if found:
        mtch = Application.match(srcRng.offset(, 1).value, A, 0) 'match it in the area reange
        If IsNumeric(mtch) Then
            addToRange rngU, A.cells(mtch) 'put it in the Union range to be colored at once, at the end
        End If
    End If
 Next A
 If Not rngU Is Nothing Then rngU.Interior.Color = vbGreen 'color the range at once
End Sub

Sub addToRange(rngU As Range, rng As Range)
    If rngU Is Nothing Then
        Set rngU = rng
    Else
        Set rngU = Union(rngU, rng)
    End If
End Sub


@Siraj Didn't you find some time to test the above code? If tested, didn't it do what you need?

Does it need to be VBA, or would Conditional Formatting suffice?
Basically, your issue has 2 steps: "get the first Number above this cell", and then… do a VLOOKUP.  In reverse order:
To check if the values match, just do =IFERROR(A1=VLOOKUP(some_value, Sheet2!$A:$B, 2, FALSE), FALSE)
Now all you need to do is figure out what some_value should be.  For that, I'm going to recommend looking at all cells above & including itself, and take the maximum Row where the value is a number:
MAX(Row(A$1:A1)*--ISNUMBER(A$1:A1))

(Note that, quite importantly, the second A1 in each range does not have a $ symbol - this means "from the top of the current column, down to the current cell")
Then, you want to get the value (not the row), so use INDEX:
INDEX($A:$A, MAX(Row(A$1:A1)*--ISNUMBER(A$1:A1)))

And plug that in to your VLOOKUP:
=IFERROR(A1=VLOOKUP(Index(A:A, MAX(Row(A$1:A1)*--ISNUMBER(A$1:A1))), Sheet2!$A:$B, 2, FALSE), FALSE)

That will give you a TRUE or FALSE result to use as a Conditional Formatting formula!

Thanks for your valuable input. But, I prefer to have VBA as this will be useful in my work.. Thanks
